# How can I use 'Generate Scripts' in SQL Server 2017 with Graph Database Objects?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017, sql-graph, sql-server-2017-graph

I'm attempting to use the `Generate Scripts` feature of SQL Server Management Studio in order to script the schema and data of a database which has Node and Edge tables included. When I select `Schema and Data` for `Types of data to script` in the Advanced options, I get the following exception, shown in the post-script failure report:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Cannot access internal graph column 'graph_id_65236D8A22184389B40ACEF8C7BA629D'

Is this a bug?

How can I use the `Generate Scripts` feature to script both schema and data for a database containing graph objects in SQL Server 2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade SSMS to the newest version:

> [Release notes for SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> SSMS 18.1
>
> SMO/scripting
>
> **Fixed an issue where "Generate Script" on a graph table fails when generating data. See UserVoice for more details.**
>
> [Generate Script on a graph table fails when generating data](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32898466)

Comment: Yup that fixed it. I wish search engines did better with bug reports and release notes, but at least it's on SO now. Thanks!